# Manipulate the objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hi I am trying to manipulate an Array having multiple objects to return a new object.

I have this-

```
var input =[
  {make:"BMW", model:"320d"},
  {make:"TATA", model:"aria"},
  {make:"Maruti", model:"800"},
  {make:"Maruti", model:"wagnor"},
  {make:"BMW", model:"720d"},
  {make:"BMW", model:"320d"}  
];
```

And I want to convert it into this-

```
output= { BMW:["320d","720d"],  Tata:['aria'],  Maruti:['800','wagonar']}
```

Please do help, I am struggling with an approach.

Comment: Can you add some examples of what you've tried? Try looking at documentation for methods in the Array prototype. You can use these on your input to reach your desired output. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: You need to iterate through each item in your `input` array, reading the value from both properties and using them to create/append a value in your `output` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group your data based on `make` key within the object

```js
var input =[
  {make:"BMW", model:"320d"},
  {make:"TATA", model:"aria"},
  {make:"Maruti", model:"800"},
  {make:"Maruti", model:"wagnor"},
  {make:"BMW", model:"720d"},
  {make:"BMW", model:"320d"}  
];

var res = input.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if(!acc[item.make]) {
     acc[item.make] = [item.model];
  } else {
    acc[item.make].push(item.model);
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` and build an object.
if `key` (make) already exist, do not add key
if `value`(model) already exist, do not add value

```js
var input = [
  { make: "BMW", model: "320d" },
  { make: "TATA", model: "aria" },
  { make: "Maruti", model: "800" },
  { make: "Maruti", model: "wagnor" },
  { make: "BMW", model: "720d" },
  { make: "BMW", model: "320d" },
];

const process = (arr) => {
  const output = {};
  arr.forEach(({ make, model }) => {
    output[make] ??= [];
    !output[make].includes(model) && output[make].push(model);
  });
  return output;
};

console.log(process(input));
```